# Remove a scheduled message from ActiveMQ Classic

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I want to be able to cancel a message sent to the queue (ActiveMQ Classic) using my Spring Boot application. I have implemented a small function to help me remove the message from the queue but it doesn't work. From digging around, I realise that the broker doesn't give you an id back(that you can use to cancel the message) when scheduling. But I have tried to test by scheduling the message, picking the id from the ActiveMQ Classic web console and hard-coding it in my function.

I would appreciate any help in figuring out what I am doing wrong in the function `scheduleMessageRemoval`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.paygokyu")
public class PaygokyuApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(PaygokyuApplication.class, args);

        JmsTemplate jms = ctx.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);

        // Schedule the message with a delay of 60 seconds
        jms.convertAndSend("javainuse", "To be consumed with delay!!!!!!", message -> {
            String scheduledMessageId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            message.setLongProperty("AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY", 60000);
            message.setStringProperty("MY_SCHEDULED_MESSAGE_ID", scheduledMessageId);

            // Schedule the message removal
            scheduleMessageRemoval(jms, message);

            return message;
        });
    }

    private static void scheduleMessageRemoval(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate, Message scheduledMessage) {
        try {
            // Get the JMS session
            Session session = jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection()
                    .createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create a topic for destination management
            Destination management = session.createTopic(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_MANAGEMENT_DESTINATION);

            // Create a message producer for the management topic
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(management);

            // Create a message to remove the scheduled task
            Message remove = session.createMessage();

            // Set message properties to specify the action and the ID of the scheduled task to remove
            remove.setStringProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION,
                    ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_REMOVE);

            String scheduledMessageID = scheduledMessage.getStringProperty("MY_SCHEDULED_MESSAGE_ID");

            System.out.println("Scheduled Message ID: " + scheduledMessageID);

            remove.setStringProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_ID, scheduledMessageID);

            
            // Send the message to the destination
            producer.send(remove);

            System.out.println("Scheduled Message REMOVED" );


            // Close the session
            session.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your code how you get the ID to the scheduled message so you need to assure that you have the correct ID.  The other thing that is unclear is what destination you are send the remove command message to, the example code below shows the basic structure of a remove operation.  The request to remove must be sent to the management destination.

```java
Destination management = session.createTopic(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_MANAGEMENT_DESTINATION);

MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(management);
Message remove = session.createMessage();

remove.setStringProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION,
                         ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_REMOVE);
remove.setStringProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_ID, <ID>);
producer.send(remove);
```

You need to know the scheduled ID which requires browsing the scheduled messages to choose which is the one you want to delete.

First thing you probably want to do is to see what messages are scheduled, so to accomplish that you need to create a Producer that publishes on the Destination named: "ActiveMQ.Scheduler.Management".  Once that's done you create a new Message and set some properties and add a Reply To destination so the scheduler knows where to send your Messages.  Then all you need to do is process the messages with a Consumer that is subscribed to that Reply To destination.

```java
Connection connection = createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

// Create the Browse Destination and the Reply To location
Destination requestBrowse = session.createTopic(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_MANAGEMENT_DESTINATION);
Destination browseDest = session.createTemporaryQueue();

// Create the "Browser"
MessageConsumer browser = session.createConsumer(browseDest);

connection.start();

// Send the browse request
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(requestBrowse);
Message request = session.createMessage();

request.setStringProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION,
                          ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_BROWSE);
equest.setJMSReplyTo(browseDest);
producer.send(request);

Message scheduled = browser.receive(5000);
while (scheduled != null) {
    // Do something clever...
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code & added your recommendations. For the sake of the test, I am generating a uuid & using it to remove the message. SInce I dont receive the Id back from the queue after sending a scheduled message

Comment: You can't just put any ID you want in there, you need to get the ID by browsing the scheduled messages from the management address.